# discord.js userinfo command results in "SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier"

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I am quite new in discord.js.

I am trying to make a userinfo command in discord.js and I keep getting an error.

Here is the code:

```js
module.exports = {
    name: "userinfo",
    description: "Userinfo of mentioned user/id or if no one mentioned then yours",
   execute(client, msg, args, guild) {
         const embed = new MessageEmbed()
   const moment = require('moment');
   const Discord = require('discord.js');

   const member =  msg.mentions.members.first() || msg.guild.members.cache.get(args[0]) || msg.member;
   if (!member) 
        return msg.channel.send('Please mention the user for the userinfo..');
      const userFlags = (await member.user.fetchFlags()).toArray();
      const activities = [];
      let customStatus;
      for (const activity of member.presence.activities.values()) {
        switch (activity.type) {
          case 'PLAYING':
            activities.push(`Playing **${activity.name}**`);
            break;
          case 'LISTENING':
            if (member.user.bot) activities.push(`Listening to **${activity.name}**`);
            else activities.push(`Listening to **${activity.details}** by **${activity.state}**`);
            break;
          case 'WATCHING':
            activities.push(`Watching **${activity.name}**`);
            break;
          case 'STREAMING':
            activities.push(`Streaming **${activity.name}**`);
            break;
          case 'CUSTOM_STATUS':
            customStatus = activity.state;
            break;
        }
      }
      const uiembed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
      .setTitle(`${member.displayName}'s Information`)
        .setThumbnail(member.user.displayAvatarURL({ dynamic: true }))
        .addField('User', member, true)
        .addField('Discriminator', `\`#${member.user.discriminator}\``, true)
        .addField('ID', `\`${member.id}\``, true)
        .addField('Status', statuses[member.presence.status], true)
        .addField('Bot', `\`${member.user.bot}\``, true)
        .addField('Color Role', member.roles.color || '`None`', true)
        .addField('Highest Role', member.roles.highest, true)
        .addField('Joined server on', `\`${moment(member.joinedAt).format('MMM DD YYYY')}\``, true)
        .addField('Joined Discord on', `\`${moment(member.user.createdAt).format('MMM DD YYYY')}\``, true)
        .setFooter(msg.member.displayName,  msg.author.displayAvatarURL({ dynamic: true }))
        .setTimestamp()
        .setColor(member.displayHexColor);
     if (activities.length > 0) uiembed.setDescription(activities.join('\n'));
      if (customStatus) uiembed.spliceFields(0, 0, { name: 'Custom Status', value: customStatus});
      if (userFlags.length > 0) uiembed.addField('Badges', userFlags.map(flag => flags[flag]).join('\n'));
      msg.channel.send(uiembed);
      }
    }
```

I get this error in the console:

```
      const userFlags = (await member.user.fetchFlags()).toArray();
                               ^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
    at wrapSafe (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:979:16)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1027:27)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1092:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:928:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:769:14)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:952:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:88:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/victor/Desktop/BIT bot/main.js:11:19)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1063:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1092:10)
```

Answer (score 2):

When using the `await` keyword like that, you need to surround whatever you are `await`ing with parentheses

```js
const userFlags = ( await (member.user.fetchFlags()) ).toArray()
```

Another, much cleaner option is making another variable for this

```js
const rawFlags = await member.user.fetchFlags()
const userFlags = rawFlags.toArray()
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so there are a few issues here.

1. Change this line `execute(client, msg, args, guild) {` to `execute: async(client, msg, args, guild) => {`
2. I'd discourage anyone to use `msg.mentions.members.first() || msg.guild.members.cache.get(args[0]) || msg.member;` despite it being easier to write. Because it only falls back to the next one if the one that it wants is `undefined` which with the nature of Discord.js, it has the intention of returning an object even though there is no one mentioned. Instead, use either ternary operators or if statements to check for the id using `msg.mentions.members.first().id`. That ensures that it will always return the person that has been mentioned. After that, you can find for the member using `await guild.members.fetch(/* The mentioned user's ID */)`.

This is all I know, I hope that my solution is helpful to you and let me know if it still doesn't work for you.

Edit: I just realised that there is no real purpose for ternary operators for this use case. I'd personally use if statements as it's easier to write it directly then to waste time defining that fallback and the managing system in ternary.